# Haskell Type errors

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, primes, typeclass

First day learning haskell, and coming from a python background I'm really having trouble debugging when it comes to type; Currently I'm working on a simple function to see if a number is a prime;

```
prime p = if p == 1 then False else if p == 2 then True else if maximum ([if p `mod` x == 0 then x else -1 | x<-[2..(floor(p**0.5))]]) > 0 then False else True
```

It works when I have a specific number instead of the generic P, but no matter what I try (and I've tried a lot, including just moving onto different problems) I always get some kind of error regarding type. For this current iteration, I'm getting the error

```
<interactive>:149:1: error:
* Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `prime'
  prevents the constraint `(RealFrac a0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the expression: prime 2
  In an equation for `it': it = prime 2

<interactive>:149:7: error:
* Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from the literal `2'
  prevents the constraint `(Num a0)' from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
    instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    ...plus two others
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the first argument of `prime', namely `2'
  In the expression: prime 2
  In an equation for `it': it = prime 2
```

If someone could, as well as debugging this particular program, give me a heads up on how to think of haskell types, I'd be incredibly grateful. I've tried looking at learnyouahaskell but so far I've had no luck applying that.

Comment: You basically want to write with this list comprehension an `all` I think.

Comment: I'd add an explicit type annotation like `prime :: Integer -> Bool`. It does not make sense for floats anyway, and the inability to determine whether to use floats is what appears to stop the automatic type inference.

Comment: Numeric types in Haskell are very rigid: no implicit conversion/promotion ever happens (but numeric literals are of the right type). `**` requires a floating type (e.g. `Double`) while `mod` requires an integral one (e.g. `Integer`). You need to perform the conversions as needed.

Comment: I've actually tried that, to no avail. I get this error:                   <interactive>:3:1: error:
    * No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `prime'
    * In the expression: prime :: Integer -> Bool
      In an equation for `it': it = prime :: Integer -> Bool

Comment: Define the function piecewise instead of trying to fit everything into nested `if` expressions. `prime 1 = False; prime 2 = True; prime p = ...`.

Comment: At the very least, boolean operators are your friend (just as in Python): `prime p = (p != 1) && ((p==2) || (...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified as

```
prime p = if p == 1 then False else 
          if p == 2 then True else 
          if maximum ([if p `mod` x == 0 then x else -1 | x<-[2..(floor(p**0.5))]]) > 0 
             then False else True
=
prime p = if p == 1 then False else 
          if p == 2 then True else 
          not (maximum [if p `mod` x == 0 then x else -1 | x<-[2..floor(p**0.5)]] > 0 )
=
prime p = not ( p == 1 ) && 
          ( p == 2 ||
            maximum [if p `mod` x == 0 then x else -1 | x<-[2..floor(p**0.5)]] <= 0 )
=
prime p = p /= 1   && 
          ( p == 2 ||
            maximum [if p `mod` x == 0 then x else -1 | x<-[2..floor(p**0.5)]] == -1 )
=~
prime p = p == 2 || p > 2 && null [x | x <- [2..floor(p**0.5)], p `mod` x == 0]
```

(convince yourself in the validity of each transformation).

This still gives us a type error of course, because `(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a` and `mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` are conflicting. To counter that, just throw a `fromIntegral` in there:

```
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime p = p == 2 || 
            p > 2 && null [x | x <- [2..floor(fromIntegral p**0.5)], p `mod` x == 0]
```

and it's working:

```
~> filter isPrime [1..100]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
```

Answer (score 4):

**In short**: by using `mod`, `floor`, and `(**)` all at the same time, you restrict the type of `p` a lot, and Haskell fails to find a numerical type to call `prime`.

The main problem here is in the iterable of your list comprehension:

```
[2..(floor(p**0.5))]
```

Here you call `p ** 0.5`, but since `(**)` has type [**`(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-), that thus means that `p` has to be an instance of a type that is an instance of the `Floating` typeclass, for example a `Float`. I guess you do not want that.

Your [**`floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor) even makes it worse, since now `p` also has to be of a type that is an instance of the `RealFrac` typeclass.

On the other hand, you use [**`mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod), so it means that your `p` has to be `Floating`, as well as `Integral`, which are rather two disjunctive sets: although strictly speaking, we can define such a type, it is rather weird for a number to be both `Integral` and `Floating` at the same type. `Float` is for instance a `Floating` number, but not `Integral`, and `Int` is `Integral`, but not a `Floating` type.

We have to find a way to relax the constraints put on `p`. Since usually non-`Integral` numbers are no primes at all, we better thus aim to throw out `floor` and `(**)`. The optimization to iterate up to the square root of `p` is however a good idea, but we will need to find other means to enforce that.

One way to do this is by using a [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) where we take elements, until the square of the numbers is greater than `p`, so we can rewrite the `[2..(floor(p**0.5))]` to:

```
takeWhile (\x -> x * x <= p) [2..]
```

We even can work only with odd elements and `2`, by writing it as:

```
takeWhile (\x -> x * x <= p) (2:[3, 5..])
```

If we test this with a `p` that is for instance set to `99`, we get:

```
Prelude> takeWhile (\x -> x * x <= 99) (2:[3, 5..])
[2,3,5,7,9]
```

If we plug that in, we relaxed the type:

```
prime p = if p == 1 then False else if p == 2 then True else if maximum ([if p `mod` x == 0 then x else -1 | x <- takeWhile (\x -> x * x <= p) (2:[3, 5..])]) > 0 then False else True
```

we actually relaxed it enough:

```
Prelude> :t prime
prime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

and we get:

```
Prelude> prime 23
True
```

But the code is very *ugly* and rather *un-Haskell*. First of all, you here use `maximum` as a trick to check if *all* elements satisfy a predicate. But it makes no sense to do that this way: from the moment one of the elements is dividable, we know that the number is not prime. So we can better use the [**`all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) function. Furthermore conditions are usually checked by using *pattern matching* and guards, so we can write it like:

```
prime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
prime n | n < 2 = False
        | otherwise = all ((/=) 0 . mod n) divisors
    where divisors = takeWhile (\x -> x * x <= n) (2:[3, 5..])
```